# Stanford 106B 2013 lib - Can not iterate struct of set

Tags: c++, struct

When I use Stanford 106B 2013 library to solve some problem, I wrote a structure then put some struct into Set:

```
struct entryT{
string firstNAME;
string lastName;
string phoneNumber;
};

bool operator<(const entryT &front,const entryT &back){
if(front.lastName < back.lastName) 
    return true;
else if(front.lastName == back.lastName  ){
    if(front.firstNAME < back.firstNAME) return true;
    else if(front.firstNAME == back.firstNAME) return false;
    else return false;
    }else return false;
}

void PrintAll(entryT stud){
cout << stud.firstNAME <<"  "<<stud.lastName << endl;
}

int main(void){
Set<entryT> students;

entryT A = {"bryan","liu","0988333222"};
entryT B = {"peggy","chang","0963333222"};
entryT C = {"penny","chang","0910022222"};

students.add(A);
students.add(B);
students.add(C);


string all = students.toString();
cout << all;

return 0;
}
```

But I get the error message:
C:\Users\root\Documents\106B-CPP\Life\lib\StanfordCPPLib\strlib.h:176: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'
    os << value;
       ^

```
the template is :
template <typename ValueType>
void writeGenericValue(std::ostream & os, const ValueType & value,
                   bool) {
   os << value;
}
```

I knew it is because the value now is struc and struct is no value pass to ostream.

How can I iterate the struct of set using this lib ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an overloaded output operator for your structure?

Comment: Could you give me more detail ? thanks

Comment: I.e. `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const entryT&);`

Comment: Thank you very much ..... solved this problem now .